# Swift - Errors which I can't solve

Tags: ios, swift, stormpath

I hope someone could assist me in solving these errors I'm getting on my Swift project.

I'm pretty new to app coding so if I sound like a noob sorry in advance.

So far I have created an app with a login and register page which is all connected together. Now I'm doing the code part which connects all these together.

I'm using user management system called StormPath and this is how the coding is done.

LoginViewController.Swift

```
import UIKit
import Stormpath

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!


    @IBAction func login(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        // Code when someone presses the login button
        Stormpath.sharedSession.login(emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!, completionHandler: openNotes)

    }

    @IBAction func loginWithFacebook(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        // Code when someone presses the login with Facebook button
    }

    @IBAction func loginWithGoogle(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        // Code when someone presses the login with Google button
    }

    @IBAction func resetPassword(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        // Code when someone presses the reset password button
        Stormpath.sharedSession.resetPassword(emailTextField.text!) { (success, error) -> Void in
            if let error = error {
                **self.showAlert(withTitle: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription)**
            } else {
                **self.showAlert(withTitle: "Success", message: "Password reset email sent!")**
            }
        }
    }

    func openNotes(success: Bool, error: NSError?) {
        if let error = error {
            **showAlert(withTitle: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription)**
        }else {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "login", sender: self)
    }
}

// Helper extension to display alerts easily.
**extension UIViewController {**
    func showAlert(withTitle title: String, message: String?) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

RegisterViewController.Swift

```
import UIKit
import Stormpath

class RegisterViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var firstNameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var lastNameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .stop, target: self, action: .exit)
    }

    func exit() {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func register(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        // Code for registering the user
       let newUser = RegistrationModel(email: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!)
        newUser.givenName = firstNameTextField.text!
        newUser.surname = lastNameTextField.text!

      // Register the new user
        Stormpath.sharedSession.register(newUser) { (account, error) -> Void in
            if let error = error {
                **self.showAlert(withTitle: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription)**
            } else {
                self.exit()
            }
        }
    }
}

private extension Selector {
    static let exit = #selector(RegisterViewController.exit)
}
```

NotesViewController.swift (Still not finished coding)

```
import UIKit
import Stormpath

class NotesViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var helloLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var notesTextView: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: .keyboardWasShown, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: .keyboardWillBeHidden, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        // Place code to load data here
        Stormpath.sharedSession.me { (account, error) -> Void in
            if let account = account {
                self.helloLabel.text = "Hello \(account.fullName)!"
            }
        }

        var request = URLRequest(url: notesEndpoint)
        request.setValue("Bearer \(Stormpath.sharedSession.accessToken ?? "")", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            guard let data = data, let json = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])) as? [String: Any], let notes = json["notes"] as? String else {
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.notesTextView.text = notes
            })
        }) 
        task.resume()
    }

    @IBAction func logout(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        // Code when someone presses the logout button
        Stormpath.sharedSession.logout()

        dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)

    }

    func keyboardWasShown(_ notification: Notification) {
        if let keyboardRect = ((notification as NSNotification).userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as AnyObject).cgRectValue {
            notesTextView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, keyboardRect.size.height, 0)
            notesTextView.scrollIndicatorInsets = notesTextView.contentInset
        }
    }

    func keyboardWillBeHidden(_ notification: Notification) {
        notesTextView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        notesTextView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    }
}

extension NotesViewController: UITextViewDelegate {

    func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        // Add a "Save" button to the navigation bar when we start editing the 
        // text field.
        **let postBody = ["notes": notesTextView.text]

        var request = URLRequest(url: notesEndpoint)**
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: postBody, options: [])
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("Bearer \(Stormpath.sharedSession.accessToken ?? "")", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request)
        task.resume()

        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .save, target: self, action: .stopEditing)
    }

    func stopEditing() {
        // Remove the "Save" button, and close the keyboard.
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil
        notesTextView.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        // Code when someone exits out of the text field

    }
}

private extension Selector {
    static let keyboardWasShown = #selector(NotesViewController.keyboardWasShown(_:))
    static let keyboardWillBeHidden = #selector(NotesViewController.keyboardWillBeHidden(_:))
    static let stopEditing = #selector(NotesViewController.stopEditing)
}
```

Now the Errors I'm having are:

- Declaration is only valid at file scope
- Expected declaration
- Use of unresolved identified 'notes endpoint'

I've been searching for hours on how to solve these errors on Google but I don't understand what's wrong with the code. If someone could guide me to what to solve would be much appreciated.

Errors - 
NotesViewController.Swift - Errors =

```
var request = URLRequest(url: notesEndpoint) - Use of unresolved identifier 'notesEndPoint'
```

LoginViewController.Swift - Errors =

```
self.showAlert(withTitle: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription) - Value of type 'LoginViewController' has no member 'showAlert'

performSegue(withIdentifier: "login", sender: self) - Implicit use of 'self' in closure; use 'self'. to make capture semantics explicit

showAlert(withTitle: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription) - Use of unresolved identifier 'showAlert'

extension UIViewController { -Declaration is only valid at file scope
```

RegisterViewController.swift -

```
self.showAlert(withTitle: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription) - Value of type 'RegisterViewController' has no member 'showAlert'
```

These are the errors I'm getting

Comment: `unresolved identifier 'notesEndpoint'` is because you are tying to use a variable that you haven't declared anywhere. (Where do you create `notesEndpoint`?)

Comment: The other errors are probably to do with a missing bracket somewhere.

Comment: You need to point out which lines exactly are giving the errors and be sure each of those lines is marked with the complete and exact error.

Comment: @JamesP - I was watching a tutorial and the tutor told us to add this code there. So to answer your question I honestly don't know.

Comment: @rmaddy - Can I mark on the coding above where the error is?

Comment: Ive added ** to where the errors are appearing.

Comment: That doesn't really help. The easiest is to add a comment line telling us what the exact error is for the line.

Comment: @rmaddy - I have added the comment above with where I'm having the errors.

Comment: It would have been so much better if you put those comments in your code.

Comment: Yes, to help us answer your questions, please add the errors in comments (like this: //error description goes here). That way we can know exactly what's going on. You could also take a screenshot and upload it.

Answer (score 2):

Your `openNotes` function is missing a bracket, this could be the cause of the first 2 errors. You should close the else:

```
func openNotes(success: Bool, error: NSError?) {
    if let error = error {
        showAlert(withTitle: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription)
    } else {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "login", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Your third error `"Use of unresolved identifier 'notesEndpoint'"` is because you are trying to use a variable that has not been declared anywhere. If your following a tutorial I guess you have missed a line like this somewhere:

`let notesEndpoint = URL(string: "https://stormpathnotes.herokuapp.com/notes")!`

Comment: Thank you :D - This solved two errors like you said.. I will go back on the tutorial and see if I can figure out what I did wrong. This is the tutorial I'm using - https://stormpath.com/blog/build-note-taking-app-swift-ios

Comment: Hey Sebbie, this is the author of the tutorial. I think I left it out by accident when I revised this for Swift 3 -- the endpoint is at `/notes` so the full line is `let notesEndpoint = URL(string: "https://stormpathnotes.herokuapp.com/notes")!`. Hope this helps!

Comment: @EdwardJiang - Thanks that worked for me :D 

Now I'm trying to create a backend so when users register it will save the /notes in StormPath database. 

I'm kinda struggling on how to do this.. I've checked out the tutorial but its not very helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

swift3

```
    let notesEndpoint = "http......."
    let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: notesEndpoint)!)
```